# Seahorse "Decrypt" context menu does not appear in Nautilus

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, gnupg, seahorse

I installed `seahorse` and `seahorse-nautilus`, so I can encrypt any file with right-click in Nautilus, that works, wonderful.

But there is no "Decrypt" menu on any file (not even `.pgp` files). Is it a bug?

[image: No decrypt]

This [2009 thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1311096) says the problems can be solved by installing `seahorse-plugins`, but:

```
$ sudo apt-get install seahorse-plugins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package seahorse-plugins is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  seahorse-nautilus:i386 seahorse-nautilus
E: Package 'seahorse-plugins' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `seahorse-plugins` is deprecated since 10.04 and as stated in the error message, the `seahorse-nautilus` package now replaces it.

For details you can look at the [source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/seahorse-nautilus) and its [`debian/control`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/seahorse-nautilus/seahorse-nautilus_3.8.0.orig.tar.xz) file:

> ```
> Package: seahorse-nautilus
> Architecture: any
> Depends: ${shlibs:Depends},
>          ${misc:Depends},
>          seahorse-daemon (>= 3.2.2)
> Recommends: seahorse
> Replaces: seahorse-plugins
> Description: seahorse plugins and utilities for encryption in GNOME
>  Seahorse nautilus is an extension for nautilus which allows encryption
>  and decryption of OpenPGP files using GnuPG - the GNU Privacy Guard 
>  program.
> ```

Regarding the missing menu item, it happens if you tried to open the encrypted file with Gedit as a new File association is then created for this new (MIME) type.

To revert such association, edit the `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file to remove (or comment) the following line:

[image]

Then restart Nautilus.

Finally to Decrypt a `.pgp` with Nautilus, right-click on it and select the **Open With Decrypt File** menu item:

[image]

Comment: That's the problem. There is no `Open With Decrypt File` item in the the Nautilus context menu, even for `.pgp` files.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I've updated my answer as I've been able to reproduce your bug

Comment: restart nautilus via terminal using: `nautilus -q && nautilus`

Comment: After installing seahorse-nautilus, double clicking on the encrypted file also works.